# Reading Samsung firmware and serial from Android phones (java)

Tags: java, android, firmware, serial-number

I'm looking for a way to read the firmware version (e.g. I9100XXKI3) from a Samsung mobile phone running Android from within an App. I know it is possible as I've seen an app already doing this however I could not find anything in the SDK docs..

Also I'm looking for the serial number (S/N as also possible to retrieve via adb -service and printed on the sticker under the battery).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [getDeviceId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29) for the IMEI number.

As for the build string use : [Build.DISPLAY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#DISPLAY)